# How to expand picture to the layout's edge

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am using an image cropper to select an image from gallery, but the image is always too small to wrap the layout horizontally. I am following the tutorial that does exactly the same, but it works for that guy

Is there a way to fix that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g54fI.jpg here is an example

Comment: You can start by adding your code, you won't get answered without it

Comment: Could you post a link with The tutorial?

Comment: Check the property `scaleType` in the imageview in the tutorial